# How to limit touch duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

Is there any method able to limit the duration of user gesture? For example, user can drag a sprite, but from cctouch begin, it only can last for 3 seconds. After the duration, the apps will auto trigger cctouch end method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend scheduling a timer using blocks. Avoid using NSTimer with Cocos2D, as it does not allow for the built-in pause/resume functionality.

Schedule as follows:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [[self scheduler] scheduleBlockForKey:@"menu" target:self interval:3.0f repeat:0 delay:0 paused:NO block:^(ccTime dt)
             {
                 // perform end of touch actions here
             }];
}
```

Also be sure to unschedule the block if the user does whatever you want before the timer is called (ccTouchEnded/ccTouchCancelled is likely):

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [[self scheduler] unscheduleBlockForKey:@"menu" target:self];
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'm new to Cocos and I didn't know that about NSTimers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is an easy strategy to achieve that. You can start a timer when the user begins to realise the gesture, and when the timer hits, stop it.

```
-(void) timerDidTick:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
    cpMouseRelease(mouse);
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerDidTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] ;
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:aTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    cpMouseGrab(mouse, touchLocation, false);
...
}
```